# Access models inside a module from Cron Commands in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want write a cron command for an Yii application. I know that to do so one can add an action in the protected.commands.

But the problem is that -

- I want to access some models that are defined in one of the modules.
- On running the command I get an some errors which imply that the models that were called are not accessibly from that action

I already checked that the `console.php` in config folder imports all the models in that module.

I don't know if there is any other settings that need to be done. Please enlighten me with a good solution.

**console.php**

```
...
'import' => array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.modules.glot.models.*',
    'application.others.ATPUtils'
),
...
```

**Glot module - model**

```
class GlotUserbatch extends Userbatch
{   
  public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
  {
    return parent::model($className);
  }
  public function rules()
  {
    return array(
      array('to_completion', 'safe'),   
    );
  }
  public function relations()
  {

  }

  public function attributeLabels()
  {
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'user_id' => 'User',
        'batch_id' => 'Batch',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but when I run crontab jobs, they run from the directory that crontab sits in "/etc/" I think. Therefore if I am including any scripts I have to give the full address "/var/www/html/...etc". I have never run cron's from Yii though, so don't know if this helps.

Comment: Please show us your `moduleName.php` and `console.php` imports

Comment: Got this one. I was actually doing a mistake in the module-model by not returning an array in `relation()`.
Anyways thanks for the help.